# Formatting Numbers conditions for SUMIFS

Tags: numbers

I have a `SUMIFS` that gets the desired result. But the condition is formatted as a string, in this case a date comparison, `"<=2023-03-21"`. The date is located in cell `B2`. How can I rewrite this condition to use the value from `B2` instead of a fixed date string value?

Comment: Have you tried constructing the date criterion within SUMIFS by concatenating the comparison operator in string and the cell B2, i.e. `"<="&B2`?

Comment: That's what I needed, but I didn't know the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @Alper I don't know if you care about reputation points on this site but if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the date criterion within SUMIFS by concatenating the comparison operator in string and the cell B2, i.e. `"<="&B2`.

This surprisingly works when the test range provided to SUMIF comprise either cells formatted as dates or cells with ISO-form dates in string format like in your case. I guess Numbers internally takes care of the data type transformations necessary in both cases so that the comparisons and filtering are made as intended.